# Creating 2d platforms using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html5-canvas, game-engine

I'm developing a HTML5 Canvas game using EaselJS and I've written a function that allows me to create "blocks" just by setting one or more images, size and position.

and by "blocks", what I mean is:

[image: this is a block] [image: this is a block compound by 9 blocks] [image: this is a block compound by 9 blocks using the second method]

### **I'm doing this using two methods:**

**First method:**

With this method the blocks are created in the available space inside the location I've set, using the images randomly.

**Second method:**

The blocks are created inside the location I've set using specific images for the top left corner, top side, top right corner, left side, center, right side, bottom left corner, bottom side and bottom right corner, and there can be more than a single image for each one of those parts (so the system uses a random one to avoid repeating the same image multiple times).

### Ok, but what's the problem?

**This function uses <strike>a zillion</strike> *77* lines** (131 lines counting with the collision-detection-related part)**!** I know there's a better way of doing this, that will take about a half or less lines than it's taking now, but I don't know how to do it and when someone show me, I'll use the *"right way"* for the rest of my life. **Can you help me?**

**What I want:**

A possible way to use less lines is to use a single "method" that allows me to create blocks that are compound by blocks that are compound by the 9-or-more images (I just don't know how to do it, and I know it's difficult to understand. Try to imagine the third image being used 9 times). **// This part of the question makes it on-topic!**

<sub>Note that this question isn't subjective, since the goal here is to use less lines, and I'm not using the EaselJS tag because the question isn't EaselJS-specific, anyone with JavaScript knowledge can answer me.</sub>

**Here's my incredibly big JavaScript function:**

```
var Graphic = function (src, blockWidth, blockHeight) {
    return {
        createBlockAt: function (x, y, blockGroupWidth, blockGroupHeight, clsdir, alpha) {
            for (var blockY = 0; blockY < blockGroupHeight / blockHeight; blockY++) {
                for (var blockX = 0; blockX < blockGroupWidth / blockWidth; blockX++) {

                    var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)]);

                    obj.width = blockWidth;
                    obj.height = blockHeight;
                    if (typeof alpha !== 'undefined') {
                        obj.alpha = alpha; // While debugging this can be used to check if a block was made over another block.
                    }

                    obj.x = Math.round(x + (blockWidth * blockX));
                    obj.y = Math.round(y + (blockHeight * blockY));

                    stage.addChild(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var complexBlock = function (topLeft, topCenter, topRight, middleLeft, middleCenter, middleRight, bottomLeft, bottomCenter, bottomRight, blockWidth, blockHeight) {
    return {
        createBlockAt: function (x, y, blockGroupWidth, blockGroupHeight, clsdir, alpha) {
            for (var blockY = 0; blockY < blockGroupHeight / blockHeight; blockY++) {
                for (var blockX = 0; blockX < blockGroupWidth / blockWidth; blockX++) {
                    if (blockY == 0 && blockX == 0) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(topLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * topLeft.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY == 0 && blockX != 0 && blockX != (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(topCenter[Math.floor(Math.random() * topCenter.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY == 0 && blockX == (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(topRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * topRight.length)]);
                    }

                    if (blockY != 0 && blockY != (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX == 0) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(middleLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * middleLeft.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY != 0 && blockY != (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX != 0 && blockX != (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(middleCenter[Math.floor(Math.random() * middleCenter.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY != 0 && blockY != (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX == (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(middleRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * middleRight.length)]);
                    }

                    if (blockY == (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX == 0) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(bottomLeft[Math.floor(Math.random() * bottomLeft.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY == (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX != 0 && blockX != (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(bottomCenter[Math.floor(Math.random() * bottomCenter.length)]);
                    }
                    if (blockY == (blockGroupHeight / blockHeight - 1) && blockX == (blockGroupWidth / blockWidth - 1)) {
                        var obj = new createjs.Bitmap(bottomRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * bottomRight.length)]);
                    }

                    obj.width = blockWidth;
                    obj.height = blockHeight;
                    if (typeof alpha !== 'undefined') {
                        obj.alpha = alpha; // While debugging this can be used to check if a block was made over another block.
                    }

                    obj.x = Math.round(x + (blockWidth * blockX));
                    obj.y = Math.round(y + (blockHeight * blockY));

                    stage.addChild(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var bigDirt = complexBlock(["http://i.imgur.com/DLwZMwJ.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/UJn3Mtb.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/AC2GFM2.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/iH6wFj0.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/wDSNzyc.png", "http://i.imgur.com/NUPhXaa.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/b9vCjrO.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/hNumqPG.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/zXvJECc.png"], ["http://i.imgur.com/Whp7EuL.png"], 40, 40);

bigDirt.createBlockAt(0, 0, 40*3, 40*3);
```

**Okay... Lots of code here, how do I test?**

Here we go: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/Dka6k/1/)

Comment: This should be asked here instead: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh... I'm new here, I didn't notice that there's a place for this specific question type. Can a moderator migrate the question?

Comment: I've updated the question to fit the community rules. I added information about a possible solution that I don't know how to execute.

Comment: the reason you have a zillion lines is because you're using a zillion images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to reduce the number of lines given the nine possible branches, but you can *substantially* reduce the repetition in your code:

```
function randomImage(arr) {
    return new createjs.Bitmap(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
}

if (blockY == 0 && blockX == 0) {
    var obj = randomImage(topLeft);
} // etc
```

Re: the nine possible branches, you should note that they are mutually exclusive, so should be using `else if` instead of just `if`, and that they are also naturally grouped in threes, suggesting that they should be nested.

**EDIT** in fact, there is a way to reduce the function size a lot.  Note that for X and Y you have three options each (nine in total).  It is possible to encode which image array you want based on a two-dimensional lookup table:

```
var blocksHigh = blockGroupHeight / blockHeight;
var blocksWide = blockGroupWidth / blockWidth;
var blockSelector = [
    [topLeft, topCenter, topRight],
    [middleLeft, middleCenter, middleRight],
    [bottomLeft, bottomCenter, bottomRight]
];

for (var blockY = 0; blockY < blocksHigh; blockY++) {
    var blockSY = (blockY == 0) ? 0 : blockY < (blocksHigh - 1) ? 1 : 2;
    for (var blockX = 0; blockX < blocksWide; blockX++) {
        var blockSX = (blockY == 0) ? 0 : blockY < (blocksWide - 1) ? 1 : 2;
        var array = blockSelector[blockSY][blockSX];
        var obj = randomImage(array);

        ...
     }
}
```

Note the definitions of `blocksHigh` and `blocksWide` outside of the loop to reduce expensive repeated division operations.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Kpj3E/

Comment: Wow, that's incredible. You reduced the code a lot! I'll study your changes and apply my changes to your code. Thank you. :)

Comment: Here's the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/Kpj3E/2/. We reduced from 112 lines to just 80!

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `blockSY` and `blockSX` vars? Removing them seems to not affect the result.

Comment: The point of those vars is to index into the `blockSelector` array.   There was a typo in my original update where I used `blockY` and `blockX` instead of `blockSY` and `blockSX` in the line starting `var array = ...`

Comment: The code fails if you use `dirt.createBlockAt(40, 40, 40 * 5, 40 * 5);`, I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: I'm already working on it - the current code works by chance for the 3x3 case, but doesn't work otherwise.  OK, I've figured it out - needs a bit more work.  BRB.

Comment: I've solved the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/Kpj3E/4/ the issue was on this line: `var blockSX = (blockY == 0) ? 0 : blockY < (blocksWide - 1) ? 1 : 2;` you typed "blockY" instead of "blockX" and as you said, you typed "blockY" and "blockX" instead of "blockSY" and "blockSX" on this line: `var array = blockSelector[blockY][blockX];`.

Comment: No, I don't think you have.  One of the changes I made was quite large, and involved iterating one whole block at a time.  I hadn't realised that your own code iterated one _pixel_ at a time.  BTW, the net result is nine separate collision objects per block - is that intended?  It would be more usual to treat the block as one object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's almost a year later now and I decided to come back here to improve the existing answers. Alnitak's suggestion on creating a "2-dimensional lookup table" was genius, but there's a even better way of doing what I was asking for.

## Sprite Sheets

The problem core is the need for picking lots of separated images and merge them in order to create a bigger mosaic. To solve this, I've merged all images into a sprite sheet. Then, with EaselJS, I've separated each part of the platform (topLeft, topCenter, etc) in multiple animations, and alternative images of the same platform part that would be used randomly are inserted within it's default part animation, as an array (so topLeft can be five images that are used randomly).

This was achieved by making a class that creates an EaselJS container object, puts the sprite sheet inside this container, moves the sprite sheet to the correct position, caches the frame and updates the container cache using the "source-overlay" compositeOperation — which puts the current cache over the last one — then it does this again until the platform is finished.

My collision detection system is then applied to the container.

**Here's the resulting JavaScript code:**

```
createMosaic = function (oArgs) { // Required arguments: source: String, width: Int, height: Int, frameLabels: Object
    oArgs.repeatX = oArgs.repeatX || 1;
    oArgs.repeatY = oArgs.repeatY || 1;

    this.self = new createjs.Container();
    this.self.set({
        x: oArgs.x || 0,
        y: oArgs.y || 0,
        width: ((oArgs.columnWidth || oArgs.width) * oArgs.repeatX) + oArgs.margin[1] + oArgs.margin[2],
        height: ((oArgs.lineHeight || oArgs.height) * oArgs.repeatY) + oArgs.margin[0] + oArgs.margin[3],
        weight: (oArgs.weight || 20) * (oArgs.repeatX * oArgs.repeatY)
    }).set(oArgs.customProperties || {});
    this.self.cache(
        0, 0,
        this.self.width, this.self.height
    );

    var _bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(oArgs.source);
    _bmp.filters = oArgs.filters || [];
    _bmp.cache(0, 0, _bmp.image.width, _bmp.image.height);

    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: [_bmp.cacheCanvas],
        frames: {width: oArgs.width, height: oArgs.height},
        animations: oArgs.frameLabels
    });

    var sprite = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
    this.self.addChild(sprite);

    for (var hl = 0; hl < oArgs.repeatY; hl++) {
        for (var vl = 0; vl < oArgs.repeatX; vl++) {
            var _yid = (hl < 1) ? "top" : (hl < oArgs.repeatY - 1) ? "middle" : "bottom";
            var _xid = (vl < 1) ? "Left" : (vl < oArgs.repeatX - 1) ? "Center" : "Right";

            if(typeof oArgs.frameLabels[_yid + _xid] === "undefined"){
                oArgs.frameLabels[_yid + _xid] = oArgs.frameLabels["topLeft"];
            } // Case the expected frameLabel animation is missing, it will default to "topLeft"
            sprite.gotoAndStop(_yid + _xid);

            if (utils.getRandomArbitrary(0, 1) <= (oArgs.alternativeTileProbability || 0) && oArgs.frameLabels[_yid + _xid].length > 1) { // If there are multiple frames in the current frameLabels animation, this code choses a random one based on probability
                var _randomPieceFrame = oArgs.frameLabels[_yid + _xid][utils.getRandomInt(1, oArgs.frameLabels[_yid + _xid].length - 1)];
                sprite.gotoAndStop(_randomPieceFrame);
            }

            sprite.set({x: vl * (oArgs.columnWidth || oArgs.width), y: hl * (oArgs.lineHeight || oArgs.height)});
            this.self.updateCache("source-overlay");
        }
    }
    this.self.removeChild(sprite);
    awake.container.addChild(this.self);
};
```

**Usage:**

```
createMosaic({
    source: "path/to/spritesheet.png",
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    frameLabels: {
        topLeft: 0, topCenter: 1, topRight: 3,
        middleLeft: 4, middleCenter: [5, 6, 9, 10], middleRight: 7,
        bottomLeft: 12, bottomCenter: 13, bottomRight: 15
    },
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    repeatX: 30,
    repeatY: 15,
    alternativeTileProbability: 75 / 100
});
```

I would recommend using the "createMosaic" as a function returned by a constructor that passes the required arguments to it, so you'll not need to write the source image path, width, height and frameLabels every time you want to create a dirt platform, for example.

Also, this answer may have more LoC than the others that came before, but it's made this way in order to have more structure.